# In C#, how can I tell if a property is static? (.Net CF 2.0)

Tags: c#, reflection, compact-framework

FieldInfo has an IsStatic member, but PropertyInfo doesn't. I assume I'm just overlooking what I need.

```
Type type = someObject.GetType();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties())
{
   // umm... Not sure how to tell if this property is static
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To determine whether a property is static, you must obtain the MethodInfo for the get or set accessor, by calling the GetGetMethod or the GetSetMethod method, and examine its IsStatic property.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo

Comment: `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

As an actual quick and simple solution to the question asked, you can use this:

```
propertyInfo.GetAccessors(nonPublic: true)[0].IsStatic;
```

Answer (score 10):

Better solution

```
public static class PropertyInfoExtensions
{
    public static bool IsStatic(this PropertyInfo source, bool nonPublic = false) 
        => source.GetAccessors(nonPublic).Any(x => x.IsStatic);
}
```

Usage:

```
property.IsStatic()
```

Answer (score 8):

Why not use

```
type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static)
```

Comment: Nice! However, in my case I want the non-static which doesn't seem to have a binding flag.

Comment: This will not give you the static binding flag of the getter

Comment: This is not a valid solution. First of all, it does not even list static properties, because binding flags should also have access level specified (`BindingFlags.Public`, `BindingFlags.NonPublic`, or both). Second of all, this simply lists static properties (input is `Type`, output is `PropertyInfo[]`), whereas the question is "given a property, how to determine if it is static?" (input is `PropertyInfo`, output is `bool`). I guess the closest thing to your proposal would be to slap `.Contains(property)` at the end, but I'd argue it would be a sub-optimal solution.