# How to get a Static property with Reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, static

So this seems pretty basic but I can't get it to work.  I have an Object, and I am using reflection to get to its public properties.  One of these properties is static and I'm having no luck getting to it.

```
Public Function GetProp(ByRef obj As Object, ByVal propName as String) as PropertyInfo
    Return obj.GetType.GetProperty(propName)
    
End Function
```

The above code works fine for Public Instance properties, which up until now is all that I have needed.  Supposedly I can use BindingFlags to request other types of properties (private, static), but I can't seem to find the right combination.

```
Public Function GetProp(ByRef obj As Object, ByVal propName as String) as PropertyInfo
    Return obj.GetType.GetProperty(propName, Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
    
End Function
```

But still, requesting any Static members return nothing.  .NET reflector can see the static properties just fine, so clearly I am missing something here.

Comment: This is really, really similar to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392122/in-c-how-can-i-tell-if-a-property-is-static-net-cf-2-0

Comment: Well it's similar in that they both use BindingFlags.  I am looking for a specific combination of BindingFlags that will allow me to get Public members, be they Static or Instance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ok so the key for me was to use the .FlattenHierarchy BindingFlag.  I don't really know why I just added it on a hunch and it started working.  So the final solution that allows me to get Public Instance or Static Properties is:

```
obj.GetType.GetProperty(propName, Reflection.BindingFlags.Public _
  Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or _
  Reflection.BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
```

Answer (score 174):

Or just look at this...

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass); // MyClass is static class with static properties
foreach (var p in type.GetProperties())
{
   var v = p.GetValue(null, null); // static classes cannot be instanced, so use null...
}
```

Comment: Which variables do these two nulls correspond to? How would you write this using named arguments, if it is possible? Thanks.

Comment: For internal static class ?

Comment: This is the best option, in my opinion it should be selected as the answer.

Comment: `p.GetValue(null);` works too. The second `null` is not required.

Comment: Looks great. The goal was to get the property based on a name argument - I don't think I would want to loop over ever property to achieve that.

Comment: @Chrono, it used to be, that's why the post included it.

Answer (score 53):

This is C#, but should give you the idea:

```
public static void Main() {
    typeof(Program).GetProperty("GetMe", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
}

private static int GetMe {
    get { return 0; }
}
```

(you need to OR NonPublic and Static only)

Comment: In my case, using only these two flags did not work. I had to also use the .FlattenHierarchy flag.

Comment: @CoreyDownie agreed. `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 51):

A little clarity...

```
// Get a PropertyInfo of specific property type(T).GetProperty(....)
PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
propertyInfo = typeof(TypeWithTheStaticProperty)
    .GetProperty("NameOfStaticProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static); 

// Use the PropertyInfo to retrieve the value from the type by not passing in an instance
object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);

// Cast the value to the desired type
ExpectedType typedValue = (ExpectedType) value;
```

Comment: `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static` solved it for me.

Answer (score 9):

```
myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static |  BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
```

This will return all static properties in static base class or a particular type and probably the child as well.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to clarify this for myself, while using the new reflection API based on `TypeInfo` - where `BindingFlags` is not available reliably (depending on target framework).

In the 'new' reflection, to get the static properties for a type (not including base class(es)) you have to do something like:

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = 
  type.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Where(p => 
    (p.GetMethod != null && p.GetMethod.IsStatic) ||
    (p.SetMethod != null && p.SetMethod.IsStatic));
```

Caters for both read-only or write-only properties (despite write-only being a terrible idea).

The `DeclaredProperties` member, too doesn't distinguish between properties with public/private accessors - so to filter around visibility, you then need to do it based on the accessor you need to use.  E.g - assuming the above call has returned, you could do:

```
var publicStaticReadable = props.Where(p => p.GetMethod != null && p.GetMethod.IsPublic);
```

There are some shortcut methods available - but ultimately we're all going to be writing a lot more extension methods around the `TypeInfo` query methods/properties in the future.  Also, the new API forces us to think about exactly what we think of as a 'private' or 'public' property from now on - because we must filter ourselves based on individual accessors.

Answer (score 1):

The below seems to work for me.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class ReflectStatic
{
    private static int SomeNumber {get; set;}
    public static object SomeReference {get; set;}
    static ReflectStatic()
    {
        SomeReference = new object();
        Console.WriteLine(SomeReference.GetHashCode());
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var rs = new ReflectStatic();
        var pi = rs.GetType().GetProperty("SomeReference",  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        if(pi == null) { Console.WriteLine("Null!"); Environment.Exit(0);}
        Console.WriteLine(pi.GetValue(rs, null).GetHashCode());


    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this [C# Reflection](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/) link.

Note I think that [BindingFlags.Instance and BindingFlags.Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f13c1950.aspx) are exclusive.

Comment: Yeah I am hoping that is not the case, because what I want i to be able to get any Public Instance or Static.

Comment: They are not exclusive. I just tested it.