# Get property Value by its stringy name

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, static

Please consider this class:

```
public static class Age
{    
    public static readonly string F1 = "18-25";
    public static readonly string F2 = "26-35";
    public static readonly string F3 = "36-45";
    public static readonly string F4 = "46-55";
}
```

I wanto to write a function that get "F1" and return "18-25".for example

```
private string GetValue(string PropertyName)
....
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply use `SWITCH` statement to perform above task:

```
public static string GetValue(string PropertyName)
{
    switch (PropertyName)
    {
        case "F1":
            return Age.F1;
        case "F2":
            return Age.F2;
        case "F3":
            return Age.F3;
        case "F4":
            return Age.F4;
        default:
            return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Using Reflection, you can do like this:

```
public static string GetValueUsingReflection(string propertyName)
{
    var field = typeof(Age).GetField(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    var fieldValue = field != null ? (string)field.GetValue(null) : string.Empty;
    return fieldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I did some testing, for this case this will work:

```
public static string GetValue(string PropertyName)
{
   return typeof(Age).GetField(PropertyName).GetValue(typeof(Age));
}
```

It seems static constants work a little different.  But the above worked with the class in the OQ.

For a more general case, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451453/how-to-get-a-static-property-with-reflection).

---

This is how it is done with reflection:

```
public static string GetValue(string PropertyName)
{
   return Age.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).ToString();
}
```

Note, GetProperty() can return null, which would crash if you passed in "F9999"

I haven't tested, you might need this:

```
public static string GetValue(string PropertyName)
{
   return Age.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName,BindingFlags.Static).ToString();
}
```

---

General case as the comment:

```
public static string GetValue(object obj, string PropertyName)
{
   return obj.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName,BindingFlags.Static).ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks,Can I pass `Class Name` to this function and don't use `Age`?

Comment: instead pass a object as the first param.

Comment: thanks but there is a problem.My class is `static` and it has not `GetType()` method. I mean this is not correct: `Age.GetType()...`

Comment: PropertyInfo.ToString() does not return the value of the property.

Comment: @kerezo _ i post what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use Reflection with Linq:

```
 private string GetValue(string propertyName)
 {
       return typeof(Age).GetFields()
           .Where(field => field.Name.Equals(propertyName))
           .Select(field => field.GetValue(null) as string)
           .SingleOrDefault();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the class [Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).
you could get the one for the class you are using withe the `getType()` function.
after you have the type use [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy.aspx) function.
you would get a [propertyinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) class. this class has a [getValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) function.
this value will return the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

try this and enjoy :

```
public static string GetValueUsingReflection(string propertyName)
    {
        var field = Type.GetType("Agenamespace" + "." + "Age").GetField(propertyName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        var fieldValue = field != null ? (string)field.GetValue(null) : string.Empty;
        return fieldValue;
    }
```

the Agenamespace is namespace that the Age class is declared in.