# get value of a property by its path in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920044/get-property-value-by-its-stringy-name) a solution is given to get value of a property of a class by supplying its name . now I wonder how I can do the same in this condition :

I have a class **MyClass** . this class ha a property of type **Foo** named **foo** . the **Foo** has a property of type **Bar** named **bar** . and bar has a string property named **value** .

properties are not static .

I want to be able to get value of **foo.bar.value** by passing the string **"foo.bar.value"** as propertyName . in other word I want to pass the property path to get its value .

is it possible ?

Comment: This is confusing: _"I want to be able to get value of ( Foo.Bar.Value ) value by passing the "Foo.Bar.Value" ."_

Comment: Can i ask why you want such a thing? That sounds rather weird and prone to errors.

Comment: @TimSchmelter , well the class comes from the client . so the function has no idea what's the structure . so the path must be given too . for some reason's I can't use interface to force a structure

Comment: What if the class changes in future? Why can't you add a reference to the dll? How do you want to get a property of a class that you cannot access?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ,sorry if my explanation was not clear . the function gets an instance of the user class , aside with path to the property it needs for its operation , through its parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive method. Each call takes the value with the first word in path and call the method again with the rest of the part.

```
public object GetPropertyValue(object o, string path)
{
    var propertyNames = path.Split('.');
    var value = o.GetType().GetProperty(propertyNames[0]).GetValue(o, null);

    if (propertyNames.Length == 1 || value == null)
        return value;
    else
    {
        return GetPropertyValue(value, path.Replace(propertyNames[0] + ".", ""));
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this might not work for an empty `path` argument. Also, it relies on the properties never assuming a `null` value.

Comment: @Amiram Korach : thank you , what about the performance . is this approach a good choice ?

Comment: Reflection is not so fast, however usually you do other things in the process like getting data from database or from a service which are much slower. You need to measure the time and see.

Comment: One other caution - If the property name shows up twice in a path E.G. MyObject.Child.Child both properties will be removed by the path.Replace when it recurses. SubString might be a safer way to go.

Answer (score 4):

*This assumes that the properties are named like the classes. i.e. that the property of Type `Foo` is also named `Foo`. Without this assumption, the question is lacking some crucial information.*

You can use the [`string.Split` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to separate the string `foo.bar.value` at the dots. You will then have an array with one element per property name.

Iterate over that array and use [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385.aspx) to retrieve the value of the properties. The value returned in one operation is the instance passed to `GetValue` in the following iteration.

```
string props = "foo.bar.value";
object currentObject = // your MyClass instance

string[] propertyChain = props.Split('.');
foreach (string propertyName in propertyChain) {
    if (propertyName == "") {
        break;
    }

    PropertyInfo prop = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    currentObject = prop.GetValue(currentObject);
    if (currentObject == null) {
        // somehow handle the situation that one of the properties is null
    }
}
```

**Update:** I have added a safeguard to ensure this will work even if `props` is empty. In that case, `currentObject` will remain a reference to the original `MyClass` instance.

Comment: @reza: I have updated the answer to use the lower-case property names.

Answer (score 1):

As You pointing to answer of the question here , You need to make use of Reglection to achieve same thing.

With help of reflection you can read value of property.

something like this,

```
// dynamically load assembly from file Test.dll
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\Test.dll");
// get type of class Calculator from just loaded assembly
Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Test.Calculator");
// create instance of class Calculator
object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);
// get info about property: public double Number
PropertyInfo numberPropertyInfo = calcType.GetProperty("Number");
// get value of property: public double Number
double value = (double)numberPropertyInfo.GetValue(calcInstance, null);
```

you need a put the code in one function and than split string as per you requirement

```
public object getvalue(string propname)
{
  //above code with return type object 
}
String[] array = string.Split("foo.bar.value");
//call above method to get value of property..
```

Read for detail : http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/

Comment: This is not an answer. The OP already knew how to read the value of a property. The question is about how to get the value of a property nested in child objects.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming FOO is static, you can get the class from a string like this:

[C# Reflection: How to get class reference from string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044455/c-sharp-reflection-how-to-get-class-reference-from-string)

...and then use the rest of the post you've linked to to get the property and value from there:

[Get property Value by its stringy name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920044/get-property-value-by-its-stringy-name)

If FOO isn't static, you'll need to use reflection on the instance (which would negate the requirement to pass in the name of the class as a string, since you can get the class from the instance with GetType()) - remembering that Bar won't have a value in the class unless it is static.