# Getting value of static property by string name

Tags: c#

There's a great post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp) that gives a way to get the value of a property by its string name:

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Currently, I'm trying to get the value of a static property in a base class. If I try to use `BaseClass.Prop` as 'src', however, I get a null reference exception. While `src` isn't associated with an explicit instance, the value of `Prop` I'm trying to get nevertheless still exists.

Is there a workaround for static properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a static property, you cannot pass an object reference. To detect if a property-get is static, look at `propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().IsStatic`. Here's your GetPropValue method:

```
public static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
{
    var propertyInfo = src.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
    if (propertyInfo.GetGetMethod().IsStatic)
        return propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
    else
        return propertyInfo.GetValue(src, null);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't send a `src` when calling `static` properties.

```
 Type t = src.GetType();

 if (t.GetProperty(propName).GetGetMethod().IsStatic)
 {   
     src = null;
 }
 return t.GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
```

Comment: Is there a way to programatically check if the property is static?

Comment: checkout this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451453/how-to-get-a-static-property-with-reflection]

Comment: @gjdanis You need to check if the GetSetMethod or GetGetMethod methods on `PropertyInfo`, the MethodInfo will tell you if it is start.