# Return all selected property values of static class

Tags: c#, image, winforms

i have a static class named CommonImage which has properties of static Bitmap thats ready to get .
heres my actual class:

```
public static class CommonImage
    {
        public static Bitmap AccountConnected { get; }

        public static Bitmap AccountDisconnected { get; }

        public static Bitmap ArrowDownIcon { get; }

        public static Bitmap ArrowUpIcon { get; }

        public static Bitmap AutoScrollIcon { get; }

        public static Bitmap RSConsDark { get; }

        public static Bitmap RSConsLight { get; }

        public static Bitmap RSDelDark { get; }

        public static Bitmap RSDelLight { get; }
    }
```

**what i want to do:**

I want to get all properties/Image that startsWith **"RS"** and store all image in an `ImageCollection` .
and if possible no loop like foreach and forloop .

Comment: Look into a combination of reflection and linq http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451453/how-to-get-a-static-property-with-reflection

Comment: +1 that makes a lot of sense ... thanks for the tip @TGH

Comment: if `CommonImage` class was created by you, why you cannot just create static method which return needed `ImageCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
var query = typeof(CommonIcons).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("RS")).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: is there a way i can save it in an imageCollection w/o looping?

Comment: @Elegiac - This query will return property name as List<string>. You want image collection?

Comment: imageCollection was a control ... sorry i forgot to mention ... btw the list above returns "string" instead of image since youve select "name" i think ... how can we select the image instead?

Comment: @Elegiac - Yes since you mentioned 'I want to get all properties which starts with "RS"', I have fetched the property names. If you wanna fetch images then you should query `actual Data` not `definition`!

Answer (score 0):

what if you try something like this..

```
var query = typeof(CommonImage).GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Contains("RS")).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
            var ImageList = new ImageList();
            query.ForEach(propName => ImageList.Images.Add((Bitmap)typeof(CommonImage).GetProperty(propName).GetValue(typeof(CommonImage), null)));
            System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection col = ImageList.Images;
```

Comment: here I assume all "RS" properties return type will be bitmap..
Otherwise it will raise type casting exception.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go into reflection for such a non dynamic thing, just define an extra property staticly:

```
public static ImageCollection RSImages
{
   get
   {
      var ic = new ImageCollection();
      ic.Add(RSConsDark);
      ic.Add(RSConsLight);
      //etc
      return ic; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Good Idea ..FYI.. I think ImageCollection does not have constructor like this.. talking about System.Windows.Forms.ImageList.ImageCollection