# How can I check that incoming parameter is static

Tags: c#, .net, types, reflection

I have class, its constructor takes SemaphoreSlim and it must be static(if else I should throw an exception). How can I check that incoming "semaphore" parameter is static? I have tried to look through its Type, but there's no IsStatic field. The code is below

```
protected CacheService(SemaphoreSlim semaphore, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    _semaphore = semaphore;
    _memoryCache = memoryCache;
}
```

Comment: Probably this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383681/how-to-check-if-string-matches-the-name-from-any-variable-in-a-static-class might help.

Comment: Why does it have to be static? If you want to ensure the same semaphore is used for all CacheServices, why not declare a private static field? What is the actual goal?

Comment: I think you are looking for the Singleton design pattern here an [example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/singleton-design-pattern-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: @JonasH this is the constructor of an abstract class with generic type <Tresult> parameter. One <string> inheritor cache service calls another <string> cache service and they both use the same static semaphore(1,1). That's why they must have different static semaphores and the only way I see is to put static semaphores in :base() constructor. It works but I don't know how to check this condition, for such future cases

Comment: To me that sounds like something solved by making the sensitive constructors private, and use code-reviews and/or unit tests to verify that the code works as intended. As long as the public methods are foolproof I would accept some internal ugliness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is never "static", by definition. What you're really asking here is, presumably, "is the argument being passed in coming from a static field". There isn't really any way of answering that at runtime, but this *could* be validated in a custom Roslyn code analyzer. Typically you would create your own `[MustBeStatic]` attribute that you would apply to the `semaphore` parameter, and have the analyzer look for this attribute (by full name, not by type - simply because of how the compiler API works), and kick in some logic that would analyze call-sites and check the expression being passed in. This would (by necessity) result in a build-time warning or error, not a runtime exception - since Roslyn analyzers happen as part of the build.

So: it is absolutely *possible* (I've done very similar things). However! This is an absolute ton of work, using specialized and complicated APIs (the Roslyn API is powerful but very non-trivial). Honestly, unless you genuinely think you're going to use this *a lot*, I think this is better solved in code-review and testing.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, even if the calling argument was a static field, the same object could still be assigned to any number of other static, instance and local variables.